# Azure SSO OnTokenValidated is not working

Tags: c#, azure, single-sign-on, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using the below code on .net core 3.1 startups.cs class. It is not hitting the below line. In my case, I am getting a token from Azure AD and want to check if the user exists on our application database(external database). Below is the sample code I am using

> ```
> services.AddProtectedWebApi(Configuration);
>         services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
>         {
>             var existingOnTokenValidatedHandler = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;
>             options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
>             {
>                 await existingOnTokenValidatedHandler(context);
>                 context.Fail("user not avilable in database");
>                 // your code to add extra claims that will be executed after the current event implementation.
>             };
>         });
> ```

Comment: Have you looked at this - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/issues/196?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default authentication scheme in Microsoft.Identity.Web for JwtBearerOptions is **JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme** ("Bearer") as mentioned in [documet for AddProtectedWebApi method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.webapiservicecollectionextensions.addprotectedwebapi?view=azure-dotnet-preview). The authentication scheme **AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme** ("AzureADJwtBearer") is not registered so it is ignored.

Update the code by replacing **AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme** with **JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme** as shown below:

```
services.AddProtectedWebApi(Configuration);
    services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        var existingOnTokenValidatedHandler = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;
        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            await existingOnTokenValidatedHandler(context);
            context.Fail("user not avilable in database");
            // your code to add extra claims that will be executed after the current event implementation.
        };
    });
```

**Another way to extend custom token validation can be found in below code:**

```
services.AddProtectedWebApi(options =>
{
    Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents();
    options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
    {
        //your code for additional validation.
    };
}, 
options =>
{
    Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
});
```